# Linear Optimization R

Tags: r, linear-programming

I am new to optimization so please bear with me. Here is my problem:

A, B, C, D and E are percentages (18%,2%,1%,78%,1%)

Maximize sum (A(x) + B(x) + C(x) +D(x) + E(x)) ie maximize x ( x<=499572)

such that

1. A(x) <= 20076
2. B(x) <= 8619
3. C(x) <= 145
4. D(x) <= 465527
5. E(x) <= 5205

How do I frame this problem in R?

I was using LPsolve package but I am ok with any suggestions.

Comment: Forget R, you just need a simple calculator. The optimal `x` is the smallest `x` in the range which violates one of the 5 constraints (or, 499572 if none of the constraints are violated). You don't really need linear programming with just 1 decision variable. [This blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/linear-programming-in-r-an-lpsolveapi-example/) shows how to use LPsolve in R.

Comment: It is your third constraint which is binding, leading to an optimal solution of `x = 14500`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We restate the problem, omitting positivity constraints on the single scalar variable `x`, as:

```
maximize 1 * x
such that
 0.18 * x <= 20076 
 0.02 * x <= 8619 
 0.01 * x <= 145 
 0.78 * x <= 465527 
 0.01 * x <= 5205
```

so as a linear program we have the following optimum value of `x`:

```
library(lpSolve)

constr.mat <- c(.18, .02, .01, .78, .01)
RHS <- c(20076, 8619, 145, 465527, 5205)
soln <- lp("max", 1, constr.mat, "<=", RHS)
soln$solution
## [1] 14500
```

Of course, as pointed out in the comments below the question this problem can be solved trivially without linear programming by taking the least upper bound of `x`:

```
min(RHS / constr.mat)
## [1] 14500
```

### Note

If what you really meant was not the problem stated in the question but rather this 5 variable problem:

```
max 0.18 * x1 + 0.02 * x2 + 0.01 * x3 + 0.78 * x4 + 0.01 * x5
such that
 0.18 * x1 <= 20076 
 0.02 * x2 <= 8619 
 0.01 * x3 <= 145 
 0.78 * x4 <= 465527 
 0.01 * x5 <= 5205
```

then we have

```
soln2 <- lp("max", constr.mat, diag(constr.mat), "<=", RHS)
soln2$solution
## [1] 111533.3 430950.0  14500.0 596829.5 520500.0
```

Again this is trivial to compute without linear programming:

```
RHS / constr.mat
## [1] 111533.3 430950.0  14500.0 596829.5 520500.0
```

Comment: this works..thank you so much... i understand some of it. I will get back if I have more doubts :)